# How to silence output of all commands in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

My Bash script calls a lot of commands, most of them output something. I want to silence them **all**. Right now, I'm adding `&>/dev/null` at the end of most command invocations, like this:

```sh
some_command &>/dev/null
another_command &>/dev/null
command3 &>/dev/null
```

Some of the commands have flags like `--quiet` or similar, still, I'd need to work it out for all of them and I'd just rather **silence all of them by default** and only allow output explicitly, e.g., via `echo`.

Comment: You coukd just redirect the output of the outermost script.

Comment: May be a duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/redirect-all-subsequent-commands-stderr-using-exec .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `exec` command to redirect everything for the rest of the script.

You can use `3>&1` to save the old stdout stream on FD 3, so you can redirect output to that if you want to see the output.

```
exec 3>&1 &>/dev/null
some_command
another_command
command_you_want_to_see >&3
command3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function:

```
run_cmd_silent () {
    # echo "Running: ${1}"
    ${1} > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

> You can remove the commented line to print the actual command you run.

Now you can run your commands like this, e.g.:

```
run_cmd_silent "git clone git@github.com:prestodb/presto.git"
```

Comment: This introduces all kinds of problems with whitespace and parameter handling.

Comment: `"$@"` is designed for this: `run_cmd_silent() { "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1; }; run_cmd_silent git clone git@github.com:prestodb/presto.git`